# Do travel bonuses from the Shadow Walk and the Phantom Steed rituals stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, travel

The Phantom Steeds can have a speed of up to 20, and the Shadow Walk ritual multiplies overland travel speed by 5. This means a party of adventurers can potentially travel overland at a speed of up to 100.

Is there any reason why this won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suppose only 2 reasons why not, in other case it's DM decision agree this or no.

1) Shadow Walk ritual says: "You and your allies walk through shadows..." 
I'm not sure that magic created mounts can count as allies...

2) Phantom Steeds ritual says: " A phantom steed is immune to any effect 
other than damage"
Positive (like +AC bonuses or other) or negative (like decrease resistance e.t.c) have no effect on Phantom Steeds, so Shadow Walk also have no effect.

*But your character can run faster than Phantom steed, so it's reason why ritual level is higher.

Comment: Yup! Conjurations are not creatures, and so I'm pretty sure they can't be allies.