# Does a character need to be close to the ritual caster for Shadow Walk and Phantom Steed to work?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

Player A is a ritual caster and casts these two rituals. He then jumps on one of the steeds and rides off in one direction.
Player B jumps on another steed and rides in the opposite direction.

Assuming the speed bonuses stack, is this possible? Do the steeds disappear if they stray too far from the caster? Can Player B still walk through shadows if he's nowhere near the caster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've [already asked before](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25280/1204) about whether the bonuses may stack or not, I won't go into that.

#### There's no need to be near the caster

Rituals don't come with any sort of "must stay close to the caster" rule unless the ritual's effects explicitly involve that. Once you complete the ritual, its effects are brought about, and that's it.

If the caster walks away, leaves the plane or even dies, ritual effects persist unless something says otherwise: Someone brought back with Raise Dead remains alive, your repaired or enchanted equipment remains repaired or enchanted, the Phantom steeds don't disappear and nor does your ability to Shadow Walk.

Shadow Walk lasts for 8 hours, and Phantom Steeds last for 12 hours or until they take damage. Neither ritual requires the caster to stay near their steeds or those affected by Shadow Walk.